# ALSA : How to route different audio streams to different playback hardware devices on a single sound card at the same time?

Tags: alsa, libalsa

here I want different audio streams, simultaneously on two hardware playback devices (hw:0,0 and hw:0,1). Currently I am able to listen on them seperately but if I try playing them concurrently sound stops from hw:0,1 and only plays from hw:0,0 (with an Alsa Debug log saying: Resource temporarily unavailable) even when I have changed my default device to hw:0,1. These are actually slave pcms dmixed and later given to plug pulgin in my asound.conf.

When these sinks are created initially alsa gives warnings of Unknown PCM and Unknown parameters but audio renders fine though (thats why ignoring the errors as read on a forum).

So playing something like
aplay -D default /tone.wav
and 
aplay -D device1 /tone.wav
seperately, works fine but when executed together plays only device1(hw:0,0) whereas my default hw:0,1 keeps blocking which i can check through
cat /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p.

Can somebody please guide how to do it, i am trying to do it only with alsa ( not with pulse) ?

Please find the following :

**$aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: cs42888audio [cs42888-audio], device 0: HiFi cs42888-0 []
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: cs42888audio [cs42888-audio], device 1: HiFi-ASRC-FE (*) []
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: imxhdmisoc [imx-hdmi-soc], device 0: i.MX HDMI Audio Tx hdmi-hifi-0 []
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**$ cat /proc/asound/devices**

```
0: [ 0]   : control
16: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
17: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
24: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
25: [ 0- 1]: digital audio capture
32: [ 1]   : control
33:        : timer
56: [ 1- 0]: digital audio capture
64: [ 2]   : control
80: [ 2- 0]: digital audio playback
```

out of which  hw:2,0 is unavailable.

Comment: Apparently, your hardware (which you have kept a secret) does not have two independent playback devices.

Comment: @CL. Please find the hardware details in the edited post. How to know if  they are independent or not.

Comment: You'd have to know how many I2S/TDM outputs your chip has, and how many are connected to the codec. Anyway, doesn't look like it.

Comment: Thanks @CL. , I went through datasheet of CS42448-DQZ datasheet (chip onboard), out of four DACs, DAC_SDIN1 has AOUTs for I2S and TDM interface formats while other three only has I2s formats AOUT.
Anyways, if it had had that capability to play independently, can you please guide me a correct path. 
One thing I noticed lately was playing through gst-launch only makes a single alsasink i.e. alsasink0 even if both are running together, resulting in halt of one. Does this make any sense ? Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Isn't the master the i.MX? And how is it connected to the codec?

Comment: @KartikInani Did you found the solution ?